# Are Secure Desktop and separate process enough for hiding sensitive information in RAM?

Tags: windows

In my program, I have an encrypted database on the file system with a password. It is decrypted in RAM, and the sensitive data get spread out too much in RAM for mistake to be auditable easily enough. (Which rule out zeroing memory manually and using SecureString all over the place)

So what I think about doing is spawning a new process in a new windows desktop, asking the user to enter his password here, then decrypting the database, doing my stuff, then closing the child process immediately.

This make the whole thing very easy to audit. The sensitive data never leave out the child process, and the timespan where sensitive data is in RAM is limited to some milli seconds.

The question is : My solution works great only if Windows is effectively zeroing the memory after the process is closed. Is it a safe thing to assume ? (I know that the OS free the memory, but freeing and zeroing is not the same thing)

I know that the Zero Paging thread is running for zeroing dirty pages, but I don't know if it is done preemptively or lazily, nor if dirty unusued pages are swapped on disk.
But maybe I am too paranoid, since, if the attacker has access to my dirty pages, then no matter what I am doing there always be a way of getting the sensitive data.

Do you see a better solution ? (which is easy to audit, and limit how much time sensitive data is in RAM)

Comment: Are you trying to protect against some sort of buffer over-read attack?

Comment: More against clipboard key logger / user space keylogger / screenshot loggers and user space processes reading memory of other processing searching for sensitive data.

My program is in .NET I'm relatively safe about buffer over read

Comment: Please do not [cross post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/277068/22815).